# Variable in variable definition

Tags: bash, variable

Command output is assigned to a variable. There is an example:

```
aa=`curl -d '{"foo":42}' -H "Content-Type: <...>" -X POST http://... | some-cmd | other-cmd`
```

I need to parametrize a number in `'{"foo":42}'`:

```
bb=42
```

and use the variable `bb` in `aa` def. The following broken sample illustrates what I need

```
aa=`curl -d '{"foo":$bb}' -H "Cont ... <and so the same>
```

How to rewrite it nested variable definition in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes stops the variable from being expanded by the shell. User double quotes instead.

For values that does not need quoting in JSON:

```
aa=$( curl -d "{\"foo\": $bb}" -H ... )
```

or,

```
aa=$( curl -d '{"foo":'"$bb"'}' -H ... )
```

If the variable's value needs to be JSON encoded (might be needed for some strings), or if you want to let a JSON parser decide on the quoting of the value (typically needed if you are sending data read from an external source, such as user input):

```
aa=$( curl -d "$( jq -nc --arg val "$bb" '{"foo": $val}' )" -H ... )
```

or, in two steps,

```
json=$( jq -nc --arg val "$bb" '{"foo": $val}' )" )
aa=$( curl -d "$json" -H ... )
```

This uses `jq` to create the JSON document that is then used with the `-d` option for `curl`.